# Fastest way to do direct transfer of from bank IRA to brokerage IRA?

Tags: united-states, ira, brokerage

I want to transfer a my Synchrony Bank cash IRA to my Vanguard IRA.

Synchrony does not support the ACAT transfer service (Vanguard does)

Vanguard says that it will take 4 to 6 weeks for the transfer doing a non-ACAT transfer.

Is there a faster way to do this without IRS questions about an indirect transfer, etc.?

Comment: What are you trying to achieve by avoiding indirect transfers?

Comment: When you say you're trying to avoid an indirect transfer, are you hoping to avoid the 20% tax withholding, 60-day rollover window, and 1-per-year restriction? The IRS doesn't question indirect rollovers as long as you do them properly. If the check isn't made out to you (e.g. it's to "Vanguard FBO Your Name IRA #xxxx"), it's not an indirect rollover, even if you have to handle the check.

Comment: Goal is to avoid the withholding and not get a 1099-R with a distribution from Synchrony. I'm pretty sure that if Synchrony sends the check to me, "Vanguard FBO Your Name IRA #xxxx", as suggested,  synchrony will code it as a distribution. That may trigger IRS intervention, which is doable, but a pain. I will ask again, but I think that's synchrony's "rule". So even though it will be a direct rollover, if synchrony codes as a distribution, that's the problem.

Comment: @piton If it's a direct rollover as you suggest (the "Custodian FBO Your IRA" means it's direct), the IRS instructions for 1099-R distribution codes indicate it should be "G - Direct rollover and direct payment". I don't know what you mean by "IRS intervention" - the IRS doesn't really do anything for this (they just set the rules you and Synchrony must follow). You will get a 1099-R for any form of IRA distribution/rollover/conversion and that must be reported on your tax return, but there's no tax withholding on a direct rollover.

Answer (score 3):

You can request a direct cash rollover, in which your old custodian (Synchrony) will liquidate all the holdings and send a check for the full amount *to you*, but payable to *the new custodian* (I.e.: "Vanguard FBO XXX"). You will then be responsible for forwarding the check to the custodian, and they'll deposit it into your IRA account with them. Despite the check being sent through you, the money goes directly from one custodian to the other, so this is a *direct* rollover. There should be no withholding.

In the comments you mentioned that you're concerned about a 1099R being issued to you and "IRS intervention" that may be triggered.

There is **always** a 1099R issued when there's a distribution. If the money leaves the account, 1099R will be issued. Even with the ACAT transfer, you'd have a 1099R issued. The codes in box 7 of the form tell the IRS *why* the money left the account. In the case of a direct rollover (either cash or ACAT) the code would be "G". That will tell the IRS that there's no taxable income to you, and the money remains in the IRA, just with a different custodian.

I'm not sure what is the "IRS intervention" you're dreading. They will not stop your rollover. Worst case, they'll send you a letter 2 years later asking for documentation, which the 1099 should prevent from happening to begin with, but will also serve as such documentation in case they ask for it.